# How to select a row based on date conditions of another row?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have df1:

```
    State       date fips score    score1 
1 Alabama 2020-03-24    1   242      0 
2 Alabama 2020-03-26    1   538      3
3 Alabama 2020-03-28    1   720      4
4 Alabama 2020-03-21    1   131      0
5 Alabama 2020-03-15    1    23      0 
6 Alabama 2020-03-18    1    51      0
7 Texas   2020-03-14    2    80      0
7 Texas   2020-03-16    2    102     0
7 Texas   2020-03-20    2    702     1
8 Texas   2020-03-23    2    1005    1
```

I would like to see which date a State surpasses a score of `100`. I would then like to select the row 7 days after that date? For example, Alabama passes 100 on March 21st, so I would like to keep the March 28th data.

```
    State       date fips  score    score1 
3 Alabama 2020-03-28    1    720      4
8 Texas   2020-03-23    2    1005     1
```

Comment: hi its possible using group_by, please add sample data using dput()

Comment: Example data: ```library(RCurl)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

states <- read.csv(text = getURL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nytimes/covid-19-data/master/us-states.csv"))
#states <- as_tibble(states)
states$date <- as.Date(states$date)

sub_states <- states %>% filter(state %in% c("Alabama", "Texas")) 
``` Except instead of score and score 1, this is `cases` and `deaths`

Comment: It seems a lot easier with one state. Do you want to work with more than one at a time, necessarily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution `tidyverse` and `lubridate`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  #Convert date column to date format
  mutate_at(vars(date), ymd) %>%
  #Group by State
  group_by(State) %>%
  #Ignore scores under 100
  filter(score > 100) %>%
  #Stay only with the date of the first date with score over 100 + 7 days
  filter(date == min(date) + days(7))
```

Comment: This is great, say if a state passes 100 score yesterday and there isn't a row correspondent to data 7 days from then? Is that row excluded base don this? I would like that

Comment: Yeah, as there is no date that meets the required conditions (date over 100 score + 7 days) that State should not appear in the result.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `by` approach (assuming date + 7 is available).

```
res <- do.call(rbind, by(dat, dat$state, function(x) {
  st <- x[x$cases > 100, ]
  st[as.Date(st$date) == as.Date(st$date[1]) + 7, ]
}))
head(res)
#                  date      state fips cases deaths
# Alabama    2020-03-27    Alabama    1   639      4
# Alaska     2020-04-04     Alaska    2   169      3
# Arizona    2020-03-28    Arizona    4   773     15
# Arkansas   2020-03-28   Arkansas    5   409      5
# California 2020-03-15 California    6   478      6
# Colorado   2020-03-21   Colorado    8   475      6
```

Comment: To get the first date > 100, run @jay.sf's excellent code without the +7 in the third line.